# Jena: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: <A>

Tags: java, uri, jena

I'm doing a parser from a csv file that builds an RDF. Right now it just adds as property the header of the csv and it's value.
When I try to write the output as XML I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.jena.shared.BadURIException: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: <A> Code: 57/REQUIRED_COMPONENT_MISSING in SCHEME: A component that is required by the scheme is missing.
```

But when I write it as json I get correct output.

Does anyone know what I have wrong? 
code:

```
public List<Model> createRDF(File file) throws Exception { //TODO implement custom Exceptions
    Csv csv = CsvReader.convertFileToCsv(file);
    List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i < csv.lines.length; i++) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Resource r = model.createResource( "http://provisionalUri.com/" + i);
        addProperties(r, csv, model, i);
        modelList.add(model);
    }


    return modelList;
}

private void addProperties(Resource r, Csv csv, Model model, int i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < csv.lines[i].length; j++) { // if the columns have different length this will cause problems
        Property property = model.createProperty(csv.headers[j]);
        Literal value = model.createLiteral(csv.lines[i][j]);
        model.add(r, property, value);
    }

}
```

writing:

```
List<Model> models = service.createRDF(new File("./src/test/java/resources/test/Bienes_declarados_Patrimonio_mundial_de_la_UNESCO_en_España.csv"));
        for(Model model: models){
            RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, Lang.RDFXML);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDF/XML has more requirements on URIs than JSON-LD because properties will be written as XML qnames.

`model.createProperty(csv.headers[j]);` isn't a legal absolute URI unless you took care with the CSV headers.

Two things are needed:

1. Need to encode "csv.headers[j]" in case it has character that are bad for URIs.
2. Need a proper URI e.g. add a "http://HOST/" to the front:

`model.createProperty("http://example/"+encode(csv.headers[j]));`